# How to integrate a software with other software through a middle layer

Tags: java, web-services, integration

I am working on integration of a software with other software’s where I am supposed to develop a middle layer that will expose the webservices to other software’s (To make sure that there is no impact on the performance of the software as every webservice can be called with limit/min therefore not allowing direct access to webservices of software).

So here we trying to achieve is this middle layer holds the load of webservices by other software (queues, batches, database etc.) then this middle layer send the required load to the software.

Please suggest what can best approach achieve this.
[Please refer the image for more clearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E3BT.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you should look into apache-camel, mule, or ESBs.

Comment: Is using something like AWS/Azure/Google Cloud an option here?

Comment: they are simple webservices of software(SAOP as of now) which can be hosted anywhere may be inhouse or we can say AWS.